# MySQL Query Inquisition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have tried for hours and cannot figure out the answer to this question:

Provide the customer last name, transaction type, employee last name, and amount for the transaction with ID = 6.

[image: ERD]

Comment: What have u tried for hours?

Comment: `JOIN` is the keyword you should look for